# Make a subdomain to point on a specific port

Tags: linux, dns

I already checked some topic about it but didn't find any solutions (if it's possible). I have a domain that points on my server on the port 80, but, I have another important webservice running on the port 8080.
I want to know if it's possible to create a subdomain like (admin.example.com) which points on port 8080.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no. The server name is resolved by a DNS query to a single IP, to which port the connection is made is between the application and the server. For HTTP the conventional default port is 80 and HTTPS 443, if you need to use another port, you need to include it in your URL.

SRV entries in a DNS record can be used so resolve a hostname to a specific port, but this works reliably only for a handful of protocols that mandate its use.

Currently the preferable way is to set up your server with a reverse proxy to direct traffic by a specific server name (your subdomain, carried in the request headers) to your admin service. This is quite easily done using e.g. [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/).

Comment: "DNS has nothing to do with ports" not true in a generic way. It has `SRV` records that allows exactly that... except that browsers in HTTP land specifically do not use them. But other applications do, like SIP or IMAP.

Comment: So I understood well, I need to setup a reverse proxy to make my 8080 port pointing to admin.example.com? (Is it possible with apache?)

Comment: Yes, it's possible with Apache. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: Thank you so much, gonna try this out